# Take value from exec sp_executesql in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
declare @nopqty decimal(10,2)
declare @ntotamt decimal(10,2)
declare @npartno nvarchar(20)

SET @Orgcd =101
SET @npartno = "A 0001 150"

declare @qry nvarchar(4000)

SET @qry = 'SELECT @nopqty = oqty' + convert(varchar(3), @norgcd) + 
           ', @ntotamt = ocost' + convert(varchar(3), @norgcd) +
           ' FROM stock WHERE part = @npartno'

exec sp_executesql @qry
```

Error

> Must declare the scalar variable

Then I used

```
exec sp_executesql @qry, N'@nopqty decimal(10,2),@ntotamt decimal(10,2),@npartno nvarchar(20)',@nopqty=@nopqty,@ntotamt=@ntotamt,@npartno=@npartno
```

but when print @nopqty, @ntotamt it is null

How can I take out @nopqty, @ntotamt from these @qry?

I need these value for some calculation

Comment: @Orgcd is undeclared, and you cannot use double quotes to assign a varchar, use apostrophes. That aside, could you please show us @qry?

Comment: i forgot write that line declared as int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the parameter as `output`.  For example:

```
declare @name varchar(10)
exec sp_executesql 
    N'select top 1 @name = name from sys.tables',
    N'@name varchar(10) output', 
    @name = @name output
print @name
```